# ¿Como optimizar el geocoding de google maps para no sobrepasar la cuota de request limite?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

saludos y buenas tardes.

estoy en el desarrollo de un proyecto que a través del servicio de geocoding de google ubicamos a la persona y le damos diferentes acciones(que van dependiendo a la ciudad en la que estes), sin embargo. unas horas despues de haber prendido el servidor este supero el limite de couta de request por dia.

```
// a traves de un pequeño hilo pido cada x millis la ubicacion con esta api:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=numlat,numlong&key=mikey
```

sin embargo como comento anteriormente, despues de unas horas el servidor pasa por encima del limite de cuotas.

mi deseo es poder guardar la geocerca que google tiene ( la que normalmente aparece cuando pones en googlemaps el nombre de tu ciudad)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para luego con mi recurso propio (mi server) emparentar y saber si esta adentro o no. pero aun no encuentro como "guardarla" en mi base de datos.

esto me ayudaria a optimizar pues las consultas despues de tener la geocerca ingresada en mi BD seria consultada primero antes de a google, logrando asi la disminucion de los querys a google.

muchas gracias por el apoyo :) 
saludos y buena energia.

Comment: en general que texto ingresas al momento de hacer el geocoding?

Comment: el request de google me pide la latitud, longitud y mi apikey, este me retorna un json el cual me indica en diferentes jsons la localidad, departamento,municipio y pais